# javascript for loop reassignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I  have a for loop like below

```js
let oArr = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
let n = 9
let k = 5
let mArr = [] 
for (let j = 0; j < k; j++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      mArr[i] = oArr[0] + oArr[1]
    } else if (i === (n - 1)) {
      mArr[i] = oArr[i] + oArr[i - 1]
    } else {
      mArr[i] = oArr[i] + oArr[i + 1] + oArr[i - 1]
    }
  }
  console.log(`j == ${j},mArr == ${mArr}`)
  oArr = mArr
}
```

so it should be

```
mArr[1] = oArr[1] + oArr[2] + oArr[0]
```

since oArr = mArr is outside the for(i) loop

but the output I get is like below

```
mArr[1] = oArr[1]*2 + oArr[2] + oArr[0]
```

Please tell me what went wrong?
is there a misplacement of

```
oArr = mArr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
oArr = mArr
```

You are not copying the arrays, but in fact both are pointing to the very same array. So when you then do

```
mArr[0] = oArr[0] + oArr[1]
```

in the next iteration of the outer loop, you are not only modifying the first element of `mArr` but also of `oArr`. Same for all other assignments. Use

```
oArr = mArr.slice()
```

to create a copy of your array instead of both pointing to the same array.

Comment: oArr = [...mArr] would be a bit more clear. the empty slice just makes me question if there's something missing

Answer (score 0):

you should change your code as below:

```
let oArr = aRandomArray;
let n = 100;
let k = 5;

for (let j = 0; j < k; j++) {
    let mArr = []; // First create a new array for each iteration of the outer loop
    
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            mArr[i] = oArr[0] + oArr[1];
        } else if (i === (n - 1)) {
            mArr[i] = oArr[i] + oArr[i - 1];
        } else {
            mArr[i] = oArr[i] + oArr[i + 1] + oArr[i - 1];
        }
    }
    
    oArr = mArr; // Last update oArr after the inner loop has completed
}
```

creating a new mArr array within each iteration of the outer loop, you ensure that the calculations are performed on the original oArr values without any interference from previous iterations.

Then, after the inner loop is completed, you update oArr with the newly calculated values stored in mArr, I hope it helps.